# XZ coordinates for Montgomery curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, montgomery-ladder

I am learning about Elliptic curve and I reached to Montgomery curve with XZ coordinates with this equation: `b*y2=x3+a*x2+x` and regarding the information from this link: [XZ coordinates add and doubling](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html)

and I made this small code in matlab to understand the concepts:

```
% Define the elliptic curve parameters
a = 1;
b = 1;
p = 23;
% Define the base point
X1 = 8;
Y1 = 3;
Z1=1;
%Doubling
X3 = mod((X1^2-Z1^2)^2,p);
Z3 = mod(4*X1*Z1*(X1^2+a*X1*Z1+Z1^2),p);
%Addition
A = X2+Z2; %X2,Z2 Values?
B = X2-Z2;
C = X3+Z3; %X3,Z3 Does this come from Doubling?
D = X3-Z3;
DA = D*A;
CB = C*B;
X5 = (DA+CB)^2;
Z5 = X1*(DA-CB)^2; %X1 Does this come from Base Point?
```

in Doubling phase I can Understand `X1, Z1` comes from Base Point, but in Addition phase I want to understand the values `X2,Z2,X3,Z3,X1` come from where?

Because what I understand that I have base point then from doubling the base point then I got second point so obviously I have `base Point X1,Z1` and from doubling I have `X3,Z3` what about `X2,Z2`?

Comment: Any idea about it?

Comment: My trouble in understanding that web page is that I don't know what "differential addition" is.

Comment: @Myria what I understand it is to take `-R` Value as pseudo value, I am still testing it in Matlab and will come back with solution soon, I hope so!

Comment: [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6383/555) explains differential addition. Basically, you add point $P$ and $Q$ also knowing $R=Q-P$ (or is it $R=P-Q$) in advance. Unfortunately I can't immediately tell per what order indices $1/2/3$ map to $P/Q/R$, else I would make that an answer. Also I think the question's formula assumes $Z_1=1$, and otherwise you need [these](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html#diffadd-dadd-1987-m-3) slightly more complex formulas (and more modular reductions). If you solved your problem already, please make and accept an answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a novice, so I can't guarantee the correct answer, sorry.

For the initial values you mentioned, in the algorithm for curve25519, such as in [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2660267.2660370), it is specified in Algorithm 1 as: X1 = xP; X2 = 1;  Z2 = 0;  X3 = xP ;  Z3 = 1, where P2 (1, 0) should refer to the point at infinity, which makes P1 and P3 the same point. When you replace the 121666 in Algorithm 2 with (A+2)/4, you can apply to the general Montgomery curve.
This is also mentioned in Section 4.4.3 of [this article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/293.pdf).

I hope it helps:)